# geoserver wms access restriction

Tags: restriction, geoserver, wms

could somebody help me to advice how to restrict accesss to published wms to just authorized user to openlayers aplication. I mean, not to allove to somebody to just grab url for wms from sourcepage of openlayers aplication and access wms by other way.
j.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about gis and should be moved to gis.stackexchange.com